# How to make the receiver work after the app is closed

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am developing an app that will do something when the phone gets a call, so I start searching and then I discovered the **BroadcastReceiver**. I declared it in the **manifest** this way:

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneState.PhoneStateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is the **PhoneStateReceiver** class:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String state = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            new PhoneStateHandler().onIncomingCallStarted(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the **onIncomingCallStarted** method is the code that will run when the phone gets a call so don't care about it.

After some searches and tries, I discovered that the receiver doesn't work when the app is closed, so I searched again.

I discovered that I need to use **Service** to keep it running, so I deleted the previous receiver and replaced it with a service.

**Manifest**(No receiver tag (currently)):

```
<service android:name=".PhoneState.PhoneStateService" />
```

**PhoneStateService**:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class PhoneStateService extends Service {

    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        registerBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (broadcastReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
            broadcastReceiver = null;
        }
    }

    private void registerBroadcastReceiver(){
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String state = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                    new PhoneStateHandler().onIncomingCallStarted(context);
                }
            }
        };
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**:

```
startService(new Intent(this, PhoneStateService.class));
```

So now there is only service there is no receiver, this worked when the app is running but after I close it and the phone gets a call the phone will tell me that the app has stopped working, some people said that because for unknown reason when the app is closed the statement **`intent.getExtras`** is returning null, so I searched for another solution.

I had a conversation with some one and he told me to make a receiver and declare it in the **Manifest** and inside the **onReceive** method I write a code that runs an **IntentService** which will run the **onIncomingCallStarted** method, but this also didn't work.

I searched again and the result was to make a receiver and declare it in the **Manifest**:

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneState.PhoneStateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**PhoneStateReceiver**:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String state = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            new PhoneStateHandler().onIncomingCallStarted(context);
        }
    }
}
```

and make an service and declare it in the **Manifest**:

```
<service android:name=".PhoneState.PhoneStateService" />
```

The new **PhoneStateService**:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class PhoneStateService extends Service {

    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        registerBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (broadcastReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
            broadcastReceiver = null;
        }
    }

    private void registerBroadcastReceiver(){
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String state = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                    new PhoneStateHandler().onIncomingCallStarted(context);
                }
            }
        };
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**:

```
startService(new Intent(this, PhoneStateService.class));
```

but this is only working when the app is running, and that was the last search.

### Edit

The **onIncomingCallStarted** method contains at the first line:

```
Log.i("MY-TAG", "It's working!!!");
```

"The app is closed" means: when the user opens the app, the app will start and that's means it's now "running", and when the user click the home button and then click the square button which show the apps that isn't closed yet, if the user dragged the app to the left or the right the app will closed, and that means "the app is closed".

"Don't working" means that the receiver isn't receiving changes in phone state, so when the phone gets a call nothing will happen.

Comment: "the onIncomingCallStarted method is the code that will run when the phone gets a call so don't care about it" -- that would appear to be where your problem lies. So, I recommend that you edit your question and psot the code to `PhoneStateHandler`. "the receiver don't work when the app is closed" -- please explain in detail what "don't work" means and what "app is closed" means. "I discovered that I need to use Service to keep it running" -- that code will only work while the process is running.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: It's LG Nexus 5 - API level 23

Comment: Please post your entire manifest.